# Catching exception from native code (Android) in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, exception, error-handling, flutter-method-channel

If I throw an Exception in Android, it doesn't not catch it on the flutter side. I am using the MethodChannel to trigger methods on Android. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: throw them using `result.error`

Comment: you ca read this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel/invokeMethod.html